# How to get multiple values from an HTML <select> element

Tags: javascript, html

How to take the values of value1 and value2  in two variables using javascript?

```
    <select class="form-control"  id="country" name="country"> 

    <option  value="**value1**" "**value2**" >Select Item</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you ask how to get multiple values from an HTML <select> element?? Your code example isn't valid HTML, you can't write value="...." "..."

Comment: If you want to put multiple values in an element, do something like `value="**value1**" value2="**value2**"`. You can't add a value without an attribute name. Anyway, what to you want to do with the two variables in the end?

Comment: no no I was just asking is there a way for doing like that, I know the syntax of HTML is not valid but my concept is to take values from one option

Comment: Then, maybe something like this `value="**value1**/**value2**"` could be turned into multiple `option` elements using some JS.

Comment: If you want to store more than a single value, use an array or an object, value="{ 'val1': 'some data', 'val2': 'more data' }"

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own attribute. I know you probably do not want to get the element with an ID, but I don't know the context. You can just call getAttribute on the option and use any name you gave to the "custom" attribute.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>
{
  const option = document.getElementById('option');
  function init()
  {
    //Use this to get the values
    console.log(option.getAttribute('other-value'));
  }
  
  init();
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control"  id="country" name="country"> 
  <option id="option" value="value1" other-value="value2">Select Item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want to do with your piece of code,
but here is a proper way to use the `option` elements, and a way to split multiple values with a fixed separator:

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example');
example.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Console displays the “value”, and not the text, of the selected option
  console.log("option value:", example.value);
});


// Here is what I'll do with your "multiple" values
var country = document.getElementById('country');
var options = country.querySelector('option');
var values = options.value.split("/");

values.forEach(function(val) {
  country.innerHTML += "<option value=" + val + ">" + val + "</option>";
});
```

```html
<p>My simple example</p>
<select id="example" name="country"> 
    <option value="--">Select Country</option>
    <option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<p>Example with option getting splitted</p>
<select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
    <!-- Let's say your multiple values are separated by a "/" -->
    <option value="**value1**/**value2**">Select Item</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not relevant. the question is if you have multiple values in single option tag then how to fetch it

Comment: @KishanOza I modified, I didn't know what he really wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('select').on('change', function() {
      console.log( $('#country').val() );
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').data('second'));
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="form-control"  id="country" name="country"> 

            <option  value="value1" data-second ="value2" >Select Item 1</option>
           <option  value="value3" data-second ="value4" >Select Item 2</option>

            </select>
```